# Symfony2 Attribute bag

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have a problem with symfony2 session attribute bag.

The problem is that the attribute bag isn't consistent and after settings some attributes on the next request they are back to the default.

I define the session as a service like this:

```
CART_SESSION:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
    arguments:
        - @session.storage
        - @cart.session.attribute_bag
        - @session.flash_bag
cart.session.attribute_bag:
    class: Backend\Builders\PageBundle\Entity\Cart
```

Backend\Builders\PageBundle\Entity\Cart is a object implementing \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBagInterface.

In my code I do the following:

```
$this->session->getBag('Cart')->set('name', 'Georgi');
```

and it sets it properly, but on next request when I retrieve the property "name" I get it as null.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to how you use `get` method from the flash bag. `get` method also removes an element from the bag.

Some example:

```
$session->getFlashBag()->set('foo', 'bar');
if ($session->getFlashBag()->get('foo)) { // it returns array with value you've set
    $bar = $session->getFlashBag()->get('foo'); // it returns null because you already get the data above
}
```

So, make sure you don't use `get` method before you really need it (for example for checking existence of a parameter).

Comment: Ok, is there a way to use namespace in symfony2 sessions without beeing flashdata ?

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase the question? Im not sure if I get it.

Comment: If you meant if it's possible to "get" data without removing it from the flash bag, then yes - it's possible. Use "peek" method insted of "get".